# Displaying limited rows from SQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Consider  a database table with 100 rows and the table is updated ie the number of rows increases on a regular basis.

Suppose that when a visitor visits my website, my table consist Xrows, but I want only rows from (X-25) to (X-50) to be visible.

I need help to code a PHP such that only rows from (X-25) to (X-50) are visible

I am new to PHP ,SQL a help would aid me a lot :)

Comment: limiting while fetching seems more good than limiting on view. try limit on mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get last 20 records you have inserted..
if you are using auto increment primary key `orderid`,you can use the query

```
"SELECT * FROM Orders ORDER BY orderid DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[limit](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)** to show particular record.

The SQL query below says "return only 10 records, start on record 15":

```
 "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 15, 10";
```

1) Consider, you have 100 records 0-99. Ad you want to display 20 records starting from 11th record then query will be

```
"SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 11, 20";
```

2) If you want to display 1st 20 records then query will be :

```
 "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 20";
```

3) If you want to display latest 20 records then :

```
 "SELECT * FROM Orders ORDER BY orderid DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Comment: I want to display last 20 records in one page(I know how to do that). But I want to know how can I display the next 20 rows starting from (X-20)  in descending order, where X is total number of rows and is not constant ie increases by 1 on every new row in table

Comment: So you want last 20 rows of the table in descending order ?

Comment: select *  from  orders order by id desc limit 20;

Comment: I want to know how can I display the next 20 rows starting from (X-20) in descending order,in a different webpage where X is total number of rows and is not constant ie increases by 1 on every new row in table

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQl

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 25, 25` -- get 25 records after row 26

If you want row 25-50 in descending order you can do this by :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ORDERS LIMIT 25, 25) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: will it work if i use `desc` also?

Comment: see the updated answer. Thanks